# Adding explicit user info to matrix factorization

Tags: recommender-system, svd, latent-variable, matrix-decomposition

In the paper [Matrix Factorization Techniques for Recommender Systems](https://datajobs.com/data-science-repo/Recommender-Systems-%5BNetflix%5D.pdf), it is claimed that we can incorporate extra user information into our recommender model by doing something like this:
$$
\hat{r}_{ui} = \mu + b_{i} + b_{u} + q_{i}^{T}.( p_{u}+\sum_{a \in A(i)} y_a)
$$

Where $y_a$ showcases the latent factor vector for each extra user info that we have.

Say I have two extra features for every user: their age and their occupation.

My question is, what method do I have to use to find the latent factor vectors of these two features? Or simply put, are they learnt based on the ratings matrix or based on the respective explicit user data?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy But that would not make sense, as $y_a$ has to have the same dimensionality as $p_u$ in order for the addition to be defined. Besides, in some other papers, such as [this](http://www.cp.jku.at/research/papers/elahi2013aixia.pdf) (section 4, equation 1), they use the formula mentioned in my post and explicitly say that $y_a$ is a latent factor vector. If more clarification is needed, please let me know.